# lodash properties cannot be read from angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

I've started playing around with loddash and I have a small angular app that I am trying to get to work. I have seen similar SO questions around this and underscorejs. But looking at the answers I have not been able to get it to load.

Within my app.js file I create a factory to register the `'_' to window._`

```
var app = angular.module("app", [])
.constant('_', window._);

app.factory('_', ['$window', function ($window) {
    return $window._;
}]);
```

Within my html I have lodash loading before the angular libraries

```
<script src="scripts/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-loader.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/angular-animate.js"></script>

<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/treeController.js"></script>
<script src="app/treeviewDirective.js"></script>

<script src="app/test.js"></script>
```

And then within the controller I tried to inject the `'_'` service/factory

```
app.controller("treeController", ['$scope',  function($scope, _) {
    var vm = this;
    function nestAssociation(node, oldCollection, newAggregates) {

        var array = [1];
        var other = _.concat(array, 2, [3], [[4]]);

        var selectedNode = node.parent;
        var itemIndex = _.findIndex(oldCollection.children, function (o) { return o.parent == selectedNode; });
        console.log(itemIndex);
    }
```

The page builds and initializes fine where I get an error is within the function `nestAssociation()`. As soon as the first lodash function is called `_.concat` I get an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined` which indicates that the app cannot access the lodash function which I assume is because the service is not registering the `'_'` correctly.

Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: don't need both factory and constant ... use one or the other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the _ reference in your controller declaration I think?  Try this:

```
app.controller("treeController", ['$scope', '_',  function($scope, _) {
    var vm = this;
    function nestAssociation(node, oldCollection, newAggregates) {

        var array = [1];
        var other = _.concat(array, 2, [3], [[4]]);

        var selectedNode = node.parent;
        var itemIndex = _.findIndex(oldCollection.children, function (o) { return o.parent == selectedNode; });
        console.log(itemIndex);
    }
```

Comment: Also not sure you need to rely on _ being declared by dependency injection if you are registering it as a constant throughout the app.  I could be wrong though.

Comment: That was it. And you are correct I removed the constant and just left it as a service.